# If one subnet can see another does that mean that there is a bridge between two interfaces?

Tags: linux, bridge, nic, interface

This might seem like kind of a dumb question, but...say for example...

I have a router running OpenWRT or some Linux distro and that router or box has two interfaces (lets say for sake of example a wireless one and a NIC connected to a switch).  If I create a bridge between the two interfaces, computers on both subnets (one for the wireless and one on the NIC) will be able to communicate with each other even if they are on different subnets?

Or am I misinterpreting the concept of a bridge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "bridge" is a layer 2 phenomenon, which won't help you communicate between two different subnets.

What you have is a **route** (and firewall rules that permit traffic between the two subnets).

Comment: So what is a bridge then?

Comment: You can think of a bridge fulfilling the same function as a switch does.

Comment: Connects one physical connect to many physical connections?

Comment: It allows communication between two or more network devices that reside on the same layer 2 broadcast domain.